# Calculate Average from a Textfile C#

Tags: c#, average

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        var WriteToFile = new System.IO.StreamWriter("student.txt"); //create textfile in default directory
        WriteToFile.Write(txtStudNum.Text + ", " + txtStudName.Text + ", " + txtModCode.Text + ", " + txtModMark.Text);
        WriteToFile.Close();
        this.Close(); 
    }

    catch (System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException ex)
    {
        //add error message
    }
}

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    File.AppendAllText("student.txt", "\r\n" + txtStudNum.Text + ", " +  
    txtStudName.Text + ", " + txtModCode.Text + ", " + txtModMark.Text);
}

private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

I want to calculate the average for txtModMark from the textfile once all the values have been entered. It will go under button 4 so when I click it, it calculates. I need to know how to skip the first few columns per row and get to the last column to perform the average calculation.

Comment: Could you provide a sample input file?

Comment: I have it working now, thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's the point in reading from file then parse it and then convert to `INT` and then calculate average when you can do it directly using s `List<int>` like below:

declare a `List<int>` in your `Form`

```
List<int> marks = new List<int>();
```

Store the marks in button click event

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var WriteToFile = new System.IO.StreamWriter("student.txt"); //create textfile in default directory
            WriteToFile.Write(txtStudNum.Text + ", " + txtStudName.Text + ", " + txtModCode.Text + ", " + txtModMark.Text);
            WriteToFile.Close();
           marks.Add(Convert.ToInt32(txtModMark.Text)); //add to list
        }

        catch (System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException ex)
        {
            //add error message
        }
    }
```

In button4 click event calculate the average

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   int totalmarks = 0;
   foreach(int m in marks)
    totalmarks += m;

  MessageBox.Show("Average Is: " + totalmarks / marks.Count);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I have edited the code, but when I press button 4, it gives me the error, "An unhandled exception of type 'System.DivideByZeroException'"  How do I solve this? I have 3 rows in the text file but it says that I cannot divide by 0?

Comment: @VegetaZA, that means the `marks` list have no item added to it. Did you followed the answer correctly and make the modification. If so then you shouldn't get this exception.

Comment: I have found the error, I did not add "marks.Add(Convert.ToInt32(txtModMark.Text)); //add to list" to button 3. Thank you for your help, it is very appreciated!

Comment: @VegetaZA, Welcome; consider accepting the answer if it helped by clicking the check button.