# Calculate numerical string expression value

Tags: c#, expression

I have a file like this, names input.txt

```
1+2  
2+5  
8*6  
200/10
```

How can I calculate these and print them into an output.txt like below

```
1+2=3  
2+5=7  
8*6=48  
200/10=20
```

Can someone suggest me how to do this?

Comment: Show the code that you tried.

Comment: You will get an idea from this [Thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234217/is-it-possible-to-compile-and-execute-new-code-at-runtime-in-net), Iterate through each line in the file evaluate them collect result to another file. **Try this and comeback with code if you face any difficulties**

Comment: Loop through each line of text and throw every line into an Integer. Hints: File.ReadLines and For Each

Comment: I've just had some codes to read the file, using filestream and streamreader. But I don't know how to split int and string and do some calculation with the ints (new to C#, sorry)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try and show some results later

Comment: See this. It may help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32166227/calculate-average-from-a-textfile-c-sharp In stackoverflow.com, you need to show what you have tried and stuck anywhere, then everyone is here to help. Good luck!

Comment: @Fusseldieb you mean, the "+" can be an int? Sorry, I don't know that

Comment: @learningcode I just confirmed here, it doesn't work. Sorry...

Comment: @learningcode But, look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/333737/evaluating-string-342-yield-int-18

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do by `DataTable` like below-

add `System.Data` to your program. Suppose `input.txt` is your input file and `output.txt` is your output file then

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
List<string> lines = new List<string>();
var a = File.ReadAllLines("input.txt");

foreach (var s in a)
{
   lines.Add((s + "=" + dt.Compute(s, null)).Replace(" ", ""));       
}

File.WriteAllLines("output.txt", lines);
```

Comment: Wow, it really works. Thanks a lot. I really appreciate your help

Comment: Sorry, my network has a problem. I accepted and thanks again for your answer